# How draw a loess line in ts plot

Tags: r

I tried hours to figure out how I can make my loess line work. The problem is I do not know much (lets say near nothing). I only have to use R for one course in university.
I created a fake table the real table is for download [here](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22ky/monthly-total-number-of-pigs-slaughtered-in-victoria-jan-1980-august-1995#!ds=22ky&display=line)

I have to make a timeline plot that worked surprisingly well. But now I have to add two loess lines with different spans. My Problem is I don't know how the command really works. I mean I know it should be something like loess(..~.., data=..). The step where I'm stuck is marked with "WHAT BELONGS HERE" in the given code below.

```
table <- structure(list(
  Months = c("1980-06", "1980-07", "1980-08", "1980-09", 
             "1980-10", "1980-11", "1980-12", "1981-01"), 
  Total = c(75000, 70000, 60000, 73000, 72000, 71000, 76000, 71000)),
  .Names = c("Monts", "Total of Killed Pigs"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ts.obj <- ts(table$`Total of Killed Pigs`, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 2)

plot(ts.obj)

trend1 <- loess(# **WHAT BELONGS HERE?**, data = table, span =1)

predict1 <- predict(trend1)

lines(predict1, col ="blue")
```

That is my original code:

> obj <- read.csv(file="PATH/monthly-total-number-of-pigs-sla.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
>
> ts.obj <- ts(obj$Monthly.total.number.of.pigs.slaughtered.in.Victoria..Jan.1980...August.1995, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 12)
>
> plot(ts.obj)
>
> trend1 <- loess (WHAT BELONGS HERE?, data = obj, span =1)
>
> predict1 <- predict (trend1)
> lines(predict1, col="blue")

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, it's worth to learn R for more than one course. Second, Maybe use [tag:ggplot2] with ggplot(...)+ geom_smooth(method = 'loess')

Comment: Although, ideally if you could try to avoid posting links to images to code... If you want us to look at your code, ideally post the code as code

Comment: BTW, it was not me who downvoted this question. To the downvoter - why not leave a comment and say why you did this.

Comment: And have a look at dput function.

Comment: @Tjebo I tried it alredy with the original code but got a commend that I should made this table stuff to make it easier for everyone for copy paste. Thats why the original is the same as it is written here except how I got to the data :) - Thanks also for your help but I think I'm not allowed to use ggplot2 :( (it's written in the instructions) - I added now the original code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do away with the `data` argument as the time series is univariate (just one variable).

The formula `ts.obj ~ index(ts.obj)` can be read as

> *value* as a *function* of *time*

as `ts.obj` will give you the values, and `index(ts.obj)` will give you the time index for those values, and the tilde `~` specifies that the first is a function of, or dependent on, the other.

```
library(zoo) # for index()

plot(ts.obj)

trend1 <- loess(ts.obj ~ index(ts.obj), span=1)
trend2 <- loess(ts.obj ~ index(ts.obj), span=2)
trend3 <- loess(ts.obj ~ index(ts.obj), span=3)

pred <- sapply(list(trend1, trend2, trend3), predict)

matlines(index(ts.obj), pred, lty=1, col=c("blue", "red", "orange"))
```

`zoo` isn't strictly required. If you replace `index(ts.obj)` with `as.numeric(time(ts.obj))` you should be fine, I think.

[image]

Comment: @Esinede1 just as a friendly nudge:) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @AkselA thank you for your explaining answer. Now I can understand it and it works perfectly fine. You kind of saved my homework :). I was completely on the wrong track. I used it with numeric(time(ts.obj)). P.S. Sorry for the late response I was working the whole day and could only look right now if someone answered

Answer (score 0):

In case you were wanting to go with `ggplot2`:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)

 table <- structure(list(
   Months = c("1980-06", "1980-07", "1980-08", "1980-09", 
              "1980-10", "1980-11", "1980-12", "1981-01"), 
   Total = c(75000, 70000, 60000, 73000, 72000, 71000, 76000, 71000)),
   .Names = c("Months", "Total"), 
   row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Change to proper dates:

```
 table <- table %>% mutate(Months = as.Date(paste0(Months,"-01")))
```

Plot:

```
 ggplot(table, aes(x=Months, y=Total)) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_smooth(span=1, se= FALSE, color ="red") +
   geom_smooth(span=2, se= FALSE, color ="green") +
   geom_smooth(span=3, se= FALSE) +
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. It looks lot better than mine. I tried it as well and it works but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use it :( .